# 2D convolution with reparameterization using just tf.nn.convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-probability

I want to do something like what tfp.layers.Conv2DReparameterization does but simpler - no priors etc.

Given an augmented input **x** of shape *[num_particles, batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]* and a filter of mean **f_mean** and standard deviation **f_std** shape *[filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]* which are trainable variables, I use the reparameterization trick to get filter samples:

```
filter_samples = f_mean + f_std * tf.random_normal(([num_particles] + f_mean.shape))
```

Thus, filter_samples is of shape *[num_particles, filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]*.

Then, I want to do:

```
output = tf.nn.conv2d(x, filter_samples, padding='SAME') # or VALID
```

where output should be of shape *[num_particles] + standard convolution output shape*.

For dense layers, it works to just do a tf.matmul(x, filter_samples), but for conv2d I'm not sure about the results and I can't find the implementation code to check it. Implementing it myself would end up slower than TF code, so I want to avoid it.

For SAME padding, the resulting shape seems okay, for VALID the batch dim is changed making me believe it doesn't work as I expect.

Just to make it clear, I need the output to have the num_particles dim. Code is TF1.x

Any ideas on how to get that?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some code to do similar in `tfp.experimental.nn`. We can follow up in the github issues you filed/responded to.